# How to judge if matrix $A$ can transfer to matrix $B$ through row swap and column swap

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

When I try to solve circuit optimize problem I meet the following question:
How to judge if matrix $A$ can transfer to matrix $B$ through row swap and column swap in GL(n, 2) through row swap and column swap? It means that whether we can determine that exist type-1 matrices $s_1$, $s_2$, ... $s_k$ such that:
$$s_1 \cdot s_2 ... s_j \cdot A \cdot s_{j+1} ... s_{k} = B$$
type-1 matrices are row switching elementary matrices.

I thought many ways to solve this problem like: 1. sum up the matrix by rows and by colums then compare the sums. 2. sort the matrix through by rows and columns. But they all don' t work (1 is wrong and 2 is hard to proof).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Two matrices are equivalent iff their ranks are equal, so if there exist elementary matrices that reduce both $A$ and $B$ to the same rank normal form, then there exist elementary matrices to convert $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. The problem has some difference compare to dealing with 'similar matrix' or 'equivalent matrix', because it constraint on type-1 elementary matrices. And also $A$ and $B$ are both on-singular matrices since they are in GL(n, 2).

Comment: Aha, gotcha, so your question is whether there exists a check if two matrices are equal up-to a permutation. Have a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692605/how-to-tell-if-two-matrices-are-equal-up-to-a-permutation

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thank you so much!! It really help.