# When can a matrix be represented, up to a permutation, as symmetric or diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

Suppose I have a square matrix, $\textbf{A}$. I want to know whether I can represent it, it *up to a permutation of the columns*, using a symmetric or triangular matrix instead, since these only have ${n}\choose{2}$ entries instead of $n^2$.

In other words, what properties would $\textbf{A}$ need to have for a solution to exist for the following equation?

$$\textbf{A P} = \textbf{B},$$

where $\textbf{P}$ is a [permutation matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationMatrix.html) and $\textbf{B}$ is either triangular or symmetric (whichever is easier to write an answer about).

I don't need to actually find $\textbf{B}$ or compare individual pairs of $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$, so this may be simpler than some previous questions such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692605/how-to-tell-if-two-matrices-are-equal-up-to-a-permutation) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691276/algorithm-to-determine-matrix-equivalence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a column whose last $n-1$ entries are zeroes; if there isn't one, then no permutation exists. If there is, remove it, and the first row, and apply the same approach to the remaining $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. If you reach the empty matrix, then there's a permutation that does what you want. If not, then there is not.

That handles the upper-triangular case.

For the diagonal case, if the ROWS you remove all all zeroes, then you can diagonalize. (I"m not sure that this is a *complete* answer to the second question, however.)

Comment: I think I may have intended to ask a different question than the one I actually did, but your answer was very helpful for pointing that out. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of service; I tried to imagine what question you WERE trying to ask, but couldn't come up with anything but what you *did* ask, so I answered that. :)